# Vim Search Replace Regexp If this, not that, and not that

Tags: vim, regexp-replace

I have a page and I'm trying to fix abunch of links to it with regexps.

For example.   Somethings were already replaced, and they are in there like `href="/websites/site.."`, so those I'm leaving alone.  However, some were replaced from absolute to relative but the script I got that did it thought the files I was changing were at the web root directory they were..  so when i get a match like `href="/file"` I want to match.  Anywho.  Here's the regexp I'm working

```
%s#\v(href\="/)&((href\="/websites)@!|(href\="//)@!)#href="/websites/site/#g
```

However, it will change a set of entries like this

```
<a href="/websites/site/websites/site/dog.html"> 
<a href="/websites/site//">
<a href="doghouse.html">
<a href="/websites/site/doghouse.html">
```

to this

```
<a href="/websites/site/href="/websites/site/websites/site/dog.html">
<a href="/websites/site/href="/websites/site//">
<a href="doghouse.html">
<a href="/websites/site/href="/websites/site/doghouse.html">
```

Any help on getting this search/replace vim regexp right would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here goes!
`:%s/\vhref\="\/(\/|websites)@!/href="\/websites\/site`

Explanation:
All of the strings you are wanting to change begin with `href="/`, so including that as a literal seems like the right call.

Then, you want to make sure that neither the literal "websites" nor "/" are present, so that works with `(\/|website)@!`, then, you want to change it out with the new addition, so the rest is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `:help :global`. From your explaination I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but you can use this command to exclude lines with "websites" like this: `:g!'href="/websites/site/'s/LESS_COMPLICATED_REGEX/RESULT/`

Here I use `:g!` to execute command on all lines that don't match the regex in `''` (you can use `/` instead of `'` as usual). The command to execute is the ususal `:s` but here you can not worry that it will run on the lines that have "websites" string.